# Facing CSRF issue While form submission

Tags: csrf, struts-1

Hi I'm facing CSRF issue for my application while submitting form. I'm using struts 1 and i don't want to update struts, can anyone help me how to implement CSRF protection. I tried tokens but not solving the issue.

I tried tokens.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Some methods on top of my head I can think of

Use Synchronized Tokens: When generating tokens, ensure they are synchronized with the session and invalidated after a single use. This ensures that each request can use only one valid token.

Token Placement: Ensure that the token is placed in both the form as a hidden field and in the session. When a request is submitted, you can compare the token in the form with the one in the session

Double-Submit Cookies: If possible, use double-submit cookies in addition to tokens. This involves sending the token in both a cookie and a request parameter. The server can then compare both values to validate the request.

Comment: How to implement them I added token as hidden filed I'm getting bean exceptions.

Comment: If your framework supports CSRF, the server must generate   the value and you should just render it then send it back
If your framework doesn't support this (i'd be surprised) you can do this manually by generating this value and storing it alongside with the session daat